# Ajax result gone after reload

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm making a following system. If the user clicks on the follow button an ajax function is triggered. The ajax function sends data to the actions.php file and this file checks if there is data in the database. Based on this info the code inserts the follower or deletes it from the database. This works fine! But for example, if one user starts following the other person and then refresh the page the buttons HTML changes back to follow.

I have tried to do the result in PHP but it didn't work out

ajax:

```
$(".toggleFollow").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("data-userId");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions.php?action=toggleFollow",
        data: "userId=" + id,
        success: function(result) {

            if (result == "1") {

                $("button[data-userId='" + id + "']").html('<span class="icon icon-add-user"></span> Follow');

            } else if (result == "2") {

                $("button[data-userId='" + id + "']").html('<span class="icon icon-remove-user"></span> Unfollow');

            }
        }

    })

})
```

actions.php:

```
session_start();
require 'dbh.inc.php';
$id = $_SESSION['userId'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
if ($_GET['action'] == 'toggleFollow') {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM isFollowing WHERE follower = ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['userId'])." AND isFollowing = ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userId'])." LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM isFollowing WHERE id = ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['id'])." LIMIT 1");

            echo "1";

        } else {

            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO isFollowing (follower, isFollowing) VALUES (". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['userId']).", ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userId']).")");

            echo "2";


        }

}
```

I expect that the follow/unfollow button doesn't change after a refresh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior for the HTML page to reset to its original form after a page reload. You need to check whether the user is already following when rendering the button in HTML.

```
<button data-userId=2>
<?php echo isFollowing(2) ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'; ?>
</button>
```

`isFollowing()` is a placeholder for your logic that checks whether the user is already been followed.

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function isFollowing(

Comment: @MeesEgberts As mentioned, `isFollowing()` is not a real function but a placeholder for your own logic to check if the user is been follow. For example, you can define this function and use the `SELECT` query to check for  the follow state.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using `UPDATE` query

Wish code following:

```
(1) -> Go url, load database 
(2) -> Get statment is (none) Follow 
(3) -> Ajax send
(4) -> UPDATE statements (toggle) to unFollow
(5) -> Response and change html 
(6) -> Page refresh 
(7) -> back to (1)
```

With that, where Ajax send to `actions.php`, data is update inner you Database, and when refresh this page, you database reload perfect.